# Werkzeug and WebApp2 - debug display and console not working

Tags: webapp2, werkzeug

I want to use Werkzeug as a local development server and cannot get the DebugApplication middle ware to work as documented - [Werkzeug Debugging](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/). Whats wrong here?

```
import webapp2 
from system import config 
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication 
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=config.routes, debug=False, config=config.options)  
debugged_application = DebuggedApplication(application)

def main():
    run_simple('localhost', 4000, debugged_application, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True, threaded=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that DebuggedApplication middleware tries to achieve the same as `use_debugger=True`, so no need to use both. The problem is that `webapp2.WSGIApplication` adds its own error handling before it goes through the debugger middleware, thus forbidding werkzeug debugger to see the actual exception.

My solution to this is to extend base WSGIApplication provided by webapp2 to re-raise the original exception. It works with python 2.7, and will pass the exception if and only if debug flag has been set to `True` in Application constructor.

```
class Application(webapp2.WSGIApplication):
    def _internal_error(self, exception):
        if self.debug:
            raise
        return super(Application, self)._internal_error(exception)
```

Not sure this is the cleanest possible way to do it, but it works for me.